# How to show the beginning and end of a long function name in `which-key`?

Tags: spacemacs, which-key

By default, in `which-key`, descriptions that are longer than 27 characters are truncated, and `..` is added.  How can I prevent this eliding and show the beginning and end of a long function name?

Answer (score 1):

There's a customizable variable you can set: `which-key-max-description-length`

Setting it to `nil` will prevent it from truncating.

From the `describe-variable` output:

> Documentation:
>
> Truncate the description of keys to this length.
>   Also adds "..". If nil, disable any truncation.

```
(setq which-key-max-description-length nil)
```

[image: image of long function name not truncated]

Comment: I was aware of this option. However, it is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: i think if you set it to `nil` it will not truncate at all, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I want the function name to be shown like  `my-really-long..function-name`.